# How to use scrapy to scrape the value of a HTML element tag which is JSON with xpath or in another way?

Tags: json, xpath, scrapy

I using Scrapy to scrape a page and so far I had success with XPATH but I'm in a bit of a struggle with that one. I am trying to get the value of dimensionsImageKey :

```
<img id="fullViewImg" class="img-responsive"
             onerror="this.onerror = null; this.src = '/prod/Images/noImageAvalBig.jpg';"
             dimensionsImageKey="[{"k":"37081793~SID~B342~S0~I1~RW2576~H1932~TH0","w":2576,"h":1932,"sn":"","sid":37081793,"b":342,"in":1,"i":0,"s":0,"ar":1.33,"art":1.35,"tw":96,"th":72},{"k":"37081793~SID~B342~S0~I2~RW2576~H1932~TH0","w":2576,"h":1932,"sn":"","sid":37081793,"b":342,"in":2,"i":1,"s":0,"ar":1.33,"art":1.35,"tw":96,"th":72])">
```

The best I get is with

`response.xpath('//*[@dimensionsimagekey]/@dimensionsimagekey').getall()`

which only returns `'[{`

It seems that it only returns what is between two double quotes. Is there a way to achieve that with Scrapy and Xpath at all?

Comment: The given HTML does not seem valid to me, as `dimensionsImageKey` is defined as `dimensionsImageKey="[{"` since the quotes inside of the json are not escaped.

Comment: You are right, there was just a lot more data and I took the first two only. I closed it as it is, although they are still not escaped this is directly form the source.

Comment: The src tag is after the JSON and is generated with Javascript, that is why it looks invalid

Comment: But an external tool looking at this element will not be able to tell a difference, since it is not escaped properly

Comment: The attribute ends with the second quotation mark encountered, so the tool is behaving perfectly reasonably. Garbage in, garbage out.